# How to generate 4 unique digit each time form 1 to 12

Tags: random, numbers, unique

i want to generate 4 unique digit each time from 1 to 12. For example: [1,3,4,6] or [1,3,10,6] or [1,2,3,4]... but not like [1,2,8,1] or [2,2,4,5]
because in last two chunk 1 comes twice and so as 2 in second chunk. Again i need to generate those unique chunk of numbers randomly.

Any help will be appreciated. Big thanks in advance...:)

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You mean "numbers", not "digits".

Comment: programming language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript:

```
var numbers = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var uniqueNumbers = [];

function getRandom(){
    return numbers[Math.floor(Math.random()*numbers.length)];    
}

while (uniqueNumbers.length < 4){
    var value = getRandom();

    if(uniqueNumbers.indexOf(value) < 0)
        uniqueNumbers.push(value);
}

console.log(uniqueNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript

```
random: function (min,max,l){
            var arr = [],m = [],n = 0;
            if (max - min < l-1) return;
            for (var i=0; i<=(max-min); i++)m[i] = i + min;
            for (var i=0; i<l; i++) {n = Math.floor(Math.random()*(m.length)); arr[i]=m.splice(n,1);};
            return arr;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a random function and compare every generated random digit to the previous numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specify any programming language, but still try these steps whatever language you are going to use:

1. Generate a random number from 1 to 12
2. Generate second random number and check if it is same like first or not, if not than go ahead for third number and check it with first and second.
3. Repeat this process for all four digits

Implement above steps whatever programming language you want to use.

Comment: thnx...for the reply